# File get contents - Read, Change and display

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, php-7

Is it possible to read files from external website and then change some data on it and then display on the website?

Example :

Let say i have two website `example.com` & `example.net` and I want to read the file from `example.net`, make some changes to the data/variable and then printing it on `example.com`.

Let say content of Example.net :

```
<a href="http://example.net/something"><img src="happy.png" alt="Stackoverflow"></a>
```

I want to change the link from `http://example.net/something` to `http://example.com/something` and image from `happy.png` to `sad.png` and then print on example.com using `file_get_contents('https://www.example.net/')`

My Code for example.com:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.example.net/');
$homepage = str_replace("happy", "sad", $homepage);
$homepage = str_replace("example.net", "example.com", $homepage);
echo $homepage;
```

Output of example.com after read, change and display (Looking for) :

```
<a href="http://example.com/something"><img src="sad.png" alt="Stackoverflow"></a>
```

Is this possible?, If yes, Then how can i make it?. Please help!!

Comment: Sure you can. The html you receive is just a big string that you can string methods on to do what you want. As for the actual code start with a small html string in a variable, do a little research on your own , then make it change. Once you know how you can  do it to the bigger file_get_contents string

Comment: Can you help me some tag or variable?. i googled and searched many website and have no proper explanation how it can be done.

Comment: Try google searching "php replace part of string"

Comment: Is possible to change the string of the content/website without storing data in local/root folder of server?

Comment: Change it to echo it out yes. Is it the best approach? I'm not sure, that depends on how much of this you expect to do. You only asked if it was possible

Comment: Not much. just replacing all URL `example.net to example.com` and changing some images.

Comment: That would be probably better done using a config file for each site and putting the site url in a variable there. Then instead of echo the hardcode domain text echo the variable and the code will be identical on each site with exception of the value stored in the config file

Comment: I have edited my code on question. can you check if i am on correct direction?

Comment: You will know if it works won't you?

Comment: @charlietfl it working!. Thanks mate for helping me to find out solution myself. Your a good teacher. :)

Comment: So please understand that doing such research is expected before asking here. All I did was nudge you to do it yourself

Comment: Understood. Thanks again for your friendly support.